# Using link_to in a class in a Rails helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, helper, link-to

I have a rails helper using the structore below, but when I use it I get the message

```
undefined method 'link_to'
```

The helper is arranged as:

```
module MyHelper

  class Facet

    def render_for_search
      link_to("Value", params)
    end
  end

  class FacetList
    attr_accessor :facets

    def initialize
      #Create facets
    end

    def render_for_search
      result = ""
      facets.each do |facet|
        result << facet.render_for_search
      end
      result
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because within the Class Facet you don't have access to the template binding.
In order to call the `render_for_search` method you probably do something like

```
<%= Facet.new.render_for_search %>
```

Just override your `initialize` method to take the current context as argument.
The same applies to the params hash.

```
class Facet
  def initialize(context)
    @context = context
  end
  def render_for_search
    @context.link_to("Value", @context.params)
  end
end
```

Then call

```
<%= Facet.new(self).render_for_search %>
```

Otherwise, define the `render_for_search` method directly within the `MyHelper` module and don't wrap it into a class.

Comment: That works, with one minor change. In the view I had to do <%= MyHelper::Facet.new(self).render_for_search %>

Answer (score 7):

Try using this:

```
self.class.helpers.link_to
```

Because link_to is not defined in your current scope.

The above will work for a controller, but I'm guessing it will work inside another helper as well. If not then try:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
```

At the top of your helper.

Comment: This won't work because `params` is not defined within the class scope.

Comment: You can pass `params` (or just the a particular param via `params[:month]` for example) to your helper method from wherever its called, i.e. `def render_for_search(params)` which enforces the method requiring 1 argument.