# Passing a method from helper to a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a reason to pass `content_tag` method from a helper into a module:

```
module MyHelper
  def helper_method1(a, b)
    MyModule.module_method1(a, b, &content_tag)
  end
end

def MyModule
  def self.module_method1(a, b, &content_tag)
    #......
    my_tag = content_tag.call(:span, nil, class: "some_class123")
  end
end
```

The error I received is `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+)`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I do not quite have enough context to understand this question. Could you provide your file structure, the requires and the actual call that fails? Is the line that fails actually the one with the `content_tag.call`? Maybe you should try to execute the `content_tag` method in the context of `MyHelper`?

Comment: @Patru, the requirement is pass content_tag to MyModule and call it. That's it.

Comment: Please share the complete error log. Also, how are you calling `helper_method1 `. Share the relevant code.

Comment: Do you want to make this hard deliberately? I guess you want to write `module MyModule` instead of `def MyModule`, otherwise you will *only* get a `NameError: uninitialized constant MyModule`.

Comment: @Patru, the requirement is pass content_tag to MyModule and call it. That's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make it in a wrong way, in your code you try co pass block (that doesn't exists) in method 
in this case your either have to pass this to your helper method, or pass view context inside and delegate `content_at` to this context.

### Block delegation

```
 module MyHelper
  def helper_method1(a, b, &block)
    MyModule.module_method1(a, b, &block)
  end
 end

 def MyModule
   include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper

   def self.module_method1(a, b, &block)
     #......
     my_tag = content_tag(:span, &block, class: "some_class123")
   end
 end
```

### Pass view context

```
 module MyHelper
  def helper_method1(a, b)
    MyModule.module_method1(a, b, self)
  end
 end

 def MyModule
   def self.module_method1(a, b, view_context)
     my_tag = view_context.content_tag(:span, nil, class: "some_class123")
   end
 end
```

Take into account `include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper` is crucial in first example

You could check it out [Using link_to in a class in a Rails helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023751/using-link-to-in-a-class-in-a-rails-helper) it could be useful as well

Comment: sorry, I didn't get it. Why can't I pass `&content_tag` as a method to the module? `content_tag` does exist in the helper.